# calling another batch command from within batch file stops further execution

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a bat script in a folder called scr

```
/scr/
    script.bat
    test.txt 
    /folder/
        testinfolder.txt
```

When I want to copy test.txt which is in the same folder as the script, I use %~dp0 like this

```
copy %~dp0test.txt test.txt
```

What if I want to copy testinfolder.txt which is not in the same folder as the running script, but is one level deeper inside folder. How can I copy that file? I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
copy %~dp0/folder/testinfolder.txt testinfolder.txt
```

Comment: You should use `\ ` instead of `/`. Most of Windows will transparently translate `/` for you, but `cmd` is a major exception with built-in commands – since `/` is used there for command options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
copy %~dp0folder\testinfolder.txt testinfolder.txt
```

Comment: Hmm! worked for me... Could this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232651/why-the-system-cannot-find-the-batch-label-specified-is-thrown-even-if-label-ex) be the issue?  Or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522129/windows-batch-file-the-system-cannot-find-the-batch-label-specified)?

Comment: confirm, `%~dp0` already contains backslash; @Raghuram: shouldn't it be "%~dp0folder`/`testinfolder.txt"?

Comment: @barti_ddu: %~dp0 contains trailing \. File separator is / in Unix \ in Windows/DOS

Comment: @samquo - you could try creating a fresh batch file with just the relevant line and try if that works.

Comment: @Raugharm: heh, yes, of course; my addiction to bash on windows is too strong :)